# Command not found propel

Tags: php, propel

I've some problems with propel 2.0. 
I followed step by step this guide http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html but when I try with vendor/bin/propel nothing shows up. I've been trying for days, even if I create the schema and the propel.php file, when I try to run propel sql:build it says "command not found propel". Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks!!

Comment: **How** did you run it? Describe every step exactly the way you tried it. If you don't, no one can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite newbie :) btw I've done exactly everything the guide says, so I've created the composer.json file, installed propel simply with 
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
and 
php composer.phar install 
There where no errors. The guide says that you can test the installation by vendor/bin/propel and the output is supposed to be a list of options, while it shows nothing.

Comment: OK, and then the same question - what did you type and **where**? Do you even use linux or are you on windows? How did you try to run propel? What did you type? Where did you type it? There's no problem in being new to programming or computers in general, what's important is to mention exact steps so other people can reproduce them and help you. If you don't do that, we run in circles.

Comment: Ok, I'm really sorry for that! Once I created the composer.json in the project folder
 {
    "require": {
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
    }
}
I've opened putty, logged in, changed directories until i reached my project and downloaded propel with 
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
Then I installed it php composer.phar install. 
I can see all the new folders (in the vendor folder). Then I typed vendor/bin/propel, as the guide says, the command should output the propel version following by a list of the options and the available commands, but nothing shows up!

Comment: Try typing `./vendor/bin/propel`. Note the dot and slash. Also, make the file executable by using `chmod +x vendor/bin/propel` if the first command doesn't work properly.

Comment: It doesn't work with both commands, should I try with previous versions?

Comment: Well, at this point you should be getting meaningful messages, like  that file doesn't exist or that you can't change the chmod of the file, but you're not posting whether any of those happen nor what happens when you try the commands. Make sure that `vendor/bin/propel` is an actual .phar file that can be executed, it's really odd that you get *nothing* back.

Comment: I did! Still, I've just tried installing the 1.6 version and it seems to work fine! I'll go with that one, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran into the same problem, turned out I had to use:

```
php propel init
```

to make it work, instead of:

```
propel init
```